# Illegal string offset in PHP 5.4

Tags: php, drupal-6

The following code works in a computer with PHP 5.3 and it doesn't in PHP 5.4:

```
function __clone() {
  $this->changed = TRUE;
  foreach ($this->conditions as $key => $condition) {
    if (
    $condition['field']
    instanceOf QueryConditionInterface) {
      $this->conditions[$key]['field'] = clone($condition['field']);
    }
  }
}
```

`$condition` in both cases doesn't have the 'field' offset, but in PHP 5.3 the library continues working without complain, however in PHP 5.4 gives this warning message:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'field' in DatabaseCondition->__clone()
```

And short after, the library (from Drupal6), stops working.

Any idea how to fix this?

Should I use an `isset($condition['field'])` even if it's a core library of the framework?

Comment: Is it working when you use the isset?

Comment: Yes, but if possible I would like to find a better solution in order to avoid hacking the core.

Comment: I don't think that Drupal 6 supports PHP 5.4. So perhaps Upgrade to the latest version or use another PHP Version.